# Flask-restless support mysql json column type

Tags: mysql, json, flask-restless

Does flask-restless support querying across json column types? If so, how are the queries formatted?

I have a database with 3 columns that are of json type.

Example json value in addresses column is:

`{'country': 'US'}`

How should the query be formatted? The examples below do not work.

`{"filters":[{"name":"addresses.country","op":"equal","val":"US"} 
 {"filters":[{"name":"addresses","op":"equal","val":"country:US"}`